# Alternative for ExpressionEvaluationUtils in Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I upgraded my project from `Spring 3.x` to `Spring 4.x` but didn't find `ExpressionEvaluationUtils` working.
I tried googling many times but couldn't find any solution.
Here is the code:

```
protected Object evaluate(String attributeName, Object value)
    throws JspException {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        return ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluate(attributeName, (String) value,
            this.pageContext);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: It is Deprecated that's why

Comment: @sumitbadaya what is the alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions)

Spring ExpressionFactory:

```
ELContext elContext =  pageContext.getELContext();
JspFactory jf = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
JspApplicationContext jac = jf
                 .getJspApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext());
ExpressionFactory ef = jac.getExpressionFactory();
ValueExpression val = ef.createValueExpression(elContext, "expression here..", resultClass);
```